# How to get the original dimensions of a image passed to ImageView?

Tags: android

I am trying to subclass ImageView to create a custom view.

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView
```

Now I pass to MyImageView an image via `setImageResource(int resId)`

Now, I need to get the original dimensions of the image passed,

I need to do that from inside `MyImageView` so that I can use the dimension for my implementation of `onDraw()`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try `getIntrinsicHeight` and `getIntrinsicWidth` of `Drawable`?

Comment: Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();

Comment: @Stan yours is the most valuable suggestion so far. Thanks!

Comment: @LisaAnne, I can post it as an answer, so you'd accept it.

Comment: @Stan, yes, go for it

Comment: @LisaAnne, done. Why can't we vote on avatars here? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's `Drawable` provides [`getIntrinsicHeight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicHeight%28%29) and [`getIntrinsicWidth`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicWidth%28%29) methods which are supposed to return a preferred ("real" in some sense) size of an underlying drawable object, if it supports size attribute at all. I assume they should work in your case as far as you read real images, but if, for some reason, they don't (i.e. return -1), possible workarounds could be to parse image header (for example, bitmap header or SVG document, manually or using existing image libraries), or store a map with dimensions of your graphic resources along with the resources themselves.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourBitmap);`

Then try `image.getWidth` and `image.getHeight()`

**UPDATE**

you can set `decodebounds` true and pass that bounds to get `dimensions`  without decoding whole bitmap

Comment: thaks Arju but I need to taht from inside the subclass

Comment: you can get that from anywhere just pass the context if needed

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
```

Comment: thaks birdy but I need to taht from inside the subclass

Comment: so you can just call Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable()).getBitmap() to get bitmap